# Finding the residual capacity

Tags: data-structures

How to find the maximum amount by which we can increase the flow on each edge in an augmenting path in a directed graph?
Or you can say how to find the residual capacity in an augmenting path?

Answer (score 0):

Should probably consider opening your textbook to do homework rather than asking online.

Comment: I had a confusion so i had asked this question